# Citrix Application list with assigned groups

Tags: powershell

The following script gives me the list I want but I need to save the output to a file:

```
asnp citrix*
$apps = Get-BrokerApplication -MaxRecordCount 10000 -AdminAddress  khonemdc75ddc01;
$apps | ForEach-Object { 
    $array = $_.AssociatedDesktopGroupUids
    foreach ($element in $array) {
        $policy = Get-BrokerAccessPolicyRule –DesktopGroupUid $element -AllowedConnections NotViaAG
        write-host "Application: " $_.ApplicationName 
        if ($_.AssociatedUserNames) 
        {
            write-host "Users configured  using Visibility:" $_.AssociatedUserNames
            write-host '--------------------'
        }  
        else
        { 
            write-host "Users with access inherited from DG:"
            $policy.IncludedUsers;  
            write-host '--------------------'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Write-Host`cmdlet, you won't be able to pipe the output to a file - just write the string to the pipeline. To save the output, you can use the `Out-File` cmdlet:

```
asnp citrix*
$apps = Get-BrokerApplication -MaxRecordCount 10000 -AdminAddress  khonemdc75ddc01;
$apps | ForEach-Object { 
    $array = $_.AssociatedDesktopGroupUids
    foreach ($element in $array) {
        $policy = Get-BrokerAccessPolicyRule –DesktopGroupUid $element -AllowedConnections NotViaAG
        "Application: $_.ApplicationName" 
        if ($_.AssociatedUserNames) 
        {
            "Users configured  using Visibility: $_.AssociatedUserNames" 
            '--------------------'
        }  
        else
        { 
            "Users with access inherited from DG: $policy.IncludedUsers;"
            '--------------------'
        }
    }
} | Out-File -FilePath 'your_file.txt'
```

Comment: When I run your example I get this

Application: Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.Application.ApplicationName
Users with access inherited from DG: Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.AccessPolicyRule.IncludedUsers;
--------------------
Application: Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.Application.ApplicationName
Users with access inherited from DG: Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.AccessPolicyRule.IncludedUsers;
--------------------
Application: Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.Application.ApplicationName
Users with access inherited from DG: Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.AccessPolicyRule.IncludedUsers;

Answer (score 0):

Use write-ouput instead out write-host and at the end just pipe it at the end > c:\test.txt